# Caught Pokemon doesn't appear in storage after game crash

Tags: pokemon-go

I was catching a Caterpie, but my game crashed after 'Gotcha!' appeared (little pokéball spinning at the top left), so I killed the app and launched it again.

Now despite the 'Gotcha!' message, I cannot see the Caterpie in the list of Pokémon I've caught recently (the last one was a Weepinbell). I'm level 12 and this is the second time that this has happened.

I was using WiFi with my Sony C4 (Android). As far as I know, my WiFi is working fine and I don't have any GPS problems.

Comment: Did you check your log? It probably just bugged out, just because the screen displayer 'gotcha' that doesn't mean the source code already handled the event. You could contact support, but I would suggest you against it as they already are overallocated and your problem doesn't seem to be very severe.

Comment: I checked the log, and the Caterpie doesn't appear. That's not a big problem, it's just a bit frustrating. I live far away from Stops, so I'm happy when I see a Pokémon ^^

If the problem occurs another time, maybe I'll contact them. Not a big problem for a Caterpie, but if it is a Blastoise or something else...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, if  it is a rare Pokémon feel free to contact support. I simply wanted to state that you should probably make it as easy for the support as possible, believe me they have a hard life.

Comment: @Momop. I've had times where the game freezes on me as well when catching Pokemon. When this happens, I usually give the game a minute before closing it (I've noticed that doing so sometimes allows the spinning Pokeball to go away, even though the game is still visually frozen), and that will sometimes register the Pokemon was actually caught. Otherwise, if nothing in the log or recent caught shows it was there, it's probably gone for good without some support intervention.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the unreliable nature of the app, a lot of things can't really be trusted. Check your journal to see if the Caterpie was caught. If there's no entry, then that means your app wasn't able to send the information that it was caught before it froze.